# Make executable file run without prompt in linux

Tags: linux, vim

Every time I ran an executable installed in the system it's all fine without any prompt, but recently I configured my `vim` editor to do `c++` coding. Every time I build a program using make through `vim` and want to run the built executable, a pop up shows that this file is an executable and whether I want to execute it??

How do I turn that thing off so that no prompt will annoy me?

edit:
The prompt appears only when double clicking the file outside the vim editor.
using LXDE desktop on debian.

edit:
I noticed that any executable file double clicked in file manager gets the same pop up.
when launching the app through the desktop panel it is fine.

Comment: What exactly did you do to "reconfigure it for c++ coding?"

Comment: @merlin2011 gtkmm autocompletion (identifier and semantic based), syntax highlighting, background error checking, built in gdb debugger, run the program inside vim, status-line, compile only inside vim, c++ snipet insertions, comment insertions, and many other things like bufer switching and switching between files. why?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the act of confirming before running an external executable is not native to vim. That implies that one of the plugins you installed *added* that functionality, and you will have to figure out which plugin did it and most likely remove it by commenting out that part of that plugin.

Comment: actually the pop up shows outside of vim editor, ie. when double clicking the file. it runs fine inside the vim or executed in the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you did when you "configured vim to do c++", but you should simply be able to build either with a make file by running `:make` or with `g++` directory by calling:

```
:!g++ % -o %<  # calls gcc filename.ext -o filename
```

Then in like manner to run the compiled program:

```
:!./%<         # executes ./filename  (w/o extension) and without prompting
```

Comment: If you are building and attempting to run `g++` though a key map, then we will need you to post the relevant parts of your `~./vimrc` to see what is affecting your key map.

Comment: thanks, I updated my question, there is no problem running a program inside the editor but outside, double clicking the file in file explorer

Comment: Ooohh, you have a file name (or extension) association problem with your desktop. What will be needed is (1) What desktop? Gnome, KDE, XFCE, LXDE, Fluxbox? (2) what exactly did you do when **I configured my vim editor to do c++ coding**? and (3) when you are clicking your executable -- what application/file manager are you running?. It sounds like whatever you did when you configured vim changed the handling of executables not within PATH. This is desktop/file manager dependent and can be a PITA (pain in the ...) to sort out.

Comment: Also, if you are in a file manager, then right-click the executable you are attempting to launch w/o confirmation and see if there is a `Properties` or `Settings` option that applies to the file type. Sometimes it is a little icon within the `Properties` dialog that will get you to your file associations.

Comment: it's just a file created in vim with make  command, Makefile is pretty simple, no extension assigned, in properties dialog there is no default on how to open the file. what should I choose? with what application to open the file?

Comment: Sorry, now I think I understand. What you did to configure vim for c++ was run some premade Makefile in vim that **configured** vim for you. Some type of vim plugin or extension, right? Check your home directory for `~/.vimrc`. If you did run a (something) it most likely added to your ~/.vimrc. If it is there, post it.

Comment: Your issue is with PCManFM on LXDE. There **are** file properties associated with each type of file that control what happens when you click it. Take a look at [**LXDE PCManFM**](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/PCManFM#How_view_settings_change_in_one_PCManFM_window_affects_other_PCManFM_windows)

Comment: thank for lxde link, that solved my problem by adding a desktop entry for the app :)

Comment: I told you those could be a PITA!  Just helps to know where to look. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Are you on ubuntu? If so, try  open preference of the file, find behavior options, choose execute it when open.

Comment: no debian with lxde, I don't have many optoins in properties, file is marked as executable and there is no option to change properties to much :/